# Prettify JSON object alert

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object and when i alert it i get this:

[image]

and i want to get this:

[image]

```js
function getNameById(id){
    return usersArray.find(item => item.id === id).name;
}

var usersArray = [
          {"id":"135","name":"Jenny"},
                    {"id":"162","name":"Kelly"}
                 ];
$("#submit").click(function (e) {           
    var errors = {};
    
    $(".validation").each(function(){
       var worker_id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
       var w_name = getNameById(worker_id);
       if(!errors[w_name]) errors[w_name] = [];
       if ( $(this).val() == "" ) {
           errors[w_name].push( $(this).attr('id').replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '') + " must be filled!");
           //errors[w_name].push("second number must be smaller than first");
       }
       if ( $(this).attr('id') == "second-"+worker_id  && ($(this).val() > $('#first-'+worker_id+'').val())) {
         errors[w_name].push("second number must be smaller than first");
       }     
    });
    
    alert(JSON.stringify(errors, null, 2));
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  First<input id="first-135" class="validation" name="first" type="text" value="5"><br>
  Second<input id="second-135" class="validation" name="second" type="text" value="8"><br>
  Signature<input id="signature-135" class="validation" name="signature" type="text"><br>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: What does the code you've shared have to do with the question?

Comment: That is what I have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform your object to a string like this

```js
let obj = {
  "Jenny" : [
    "Second number must be smaller than first",
    "Signature must be filled !"
  ]
};

let str = "";
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
  str += k + ":\n";
  str += obj[k].join(",\n");
});

console.log(str);
```

Comment: That is exactly what i am looking for! Thank you

Comment: just change console.log to alert and it's perfect!

Comment: @lewis4u It is easier to use `console.log` to show the result here

Comment: Yes i understand, but my question is about alert, so i thought it would suit it better. Thank you one more time!

Comment: A minor detail: there'll be a missing line feed whenever the object contains more than one user.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the data from the JSON data that you have in `errors` instead of running `JSON.stringify` directly. You should be able to get the data like this: `errors["Jenny"]` to get a list of the errors. Then combine them into a string according to your liking.

Comment: And what when it is dynamic? this is all hardcoded....and in my app it is all dynamic....

Comment: Sorry but this is not an answer this should have been written in comment!

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't think your question has absolutely anything to do with JSON. The only reason why some JSON even shows up is because you're generating it for the `alert()`:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(errors, null, 2));
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This generates JSON
```

If you want to concatenate some array items you can use a combination of the [concatenation operator (`+`)](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators.html) and [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
alert(w_name + ":\n" + errors[w_name].join(",\n"));
```

Tweak format to your liking.

```js
var w_name = "Jenny";
var errors = {};

errors[w_name] = [];
errors[w_name].push("Second number must be smaller than first");
errors[w_name].push("Signature must be filled!");

alert(w_name + ":\n" + errors[w_name].join(",\n"));
```

Comment: OK i agree...can you suggest a better title for my question? So that it helps others

Comment: Concatenate strings in array?

Comment: It's miss leading, there is no word alert inside of it.

Comment: I'd dare say that the [`window.alert()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) is one order of magnitude simpler than you seem to think :)